# how to use mobile pattern in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery formatter to force the pattern for our mobile number

```
$('.mobile_number').formatter({
      'pattern': '+{{99}}-{{999}}-{{999}}-{{9999}}',
      'persistent': true
});
```

How do I add to jquery validation rule. because when the field is empty. I can only set the required.

```
$('.required').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required:  "Required"
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: you can use `pattern` attribute of HTML5. That will be more handy.

Comment: But I need to use the jquery validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7nd4ehhq/

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="phoneUS" name="phoneUS">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You can try defining your custom function as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").validate({
    rules:{
      phoneUS:
      {
        required:true,
        phoneUS:true
      }
    }  
 });

 $.validator.addMethod( "phoneUS", function( phone_number, element ) {
    return phone_number.match(/^\+[1-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/)
 }, "Please specify a valid phone number" );
});
```

**Please note:**

1) jquery validate plugin has additional validation methods already defined to validate USphonenumbers and so on. refer to https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/additional

2) In this example i have put regex based on the format you are expecting, but this can be modified to validate phone number more correctly.

Answer (score 2):

[Read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org).  There is a `pattern` rule within jQuery Validate.  However, you'll need to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).

Once included, `pattern` can be optionally declared via the HTML5 `pattern` attribute.  Otherwise, it can be declared using `.validate()` or `.rules()`, just like any other rule.

BTW - the `additional-methods.js` file already contains rules for various phone number formats that you could use.

---

As far as this code...

```
$('.required').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required:  "Required"
        }
    });
});
```

**It's totally redundant and unnecessary**.  You are matching all elements with `class="required"` and programmatically applying the `required` rule.  However, the plugin *automatically* applies the `required` rule to any form element with `class="required"`.

Comment: makes sense for your "required" class note. Cheers !!